# Postgres function returning arguments or zero value

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a stored function. I want to return columns value or zero value when a select query executed if data found. But I get syntax error. How can I solve this problem?

The error is

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "do"
>   LINE 6: do $$

My code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tuvimer.getProjectTypes(
   OUT id integer,
   OUT name character varying)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
do $$
IF EXISTS (select t.id, t.name from tuvimer.tuvi_project_category t) THEN
   RETURN t.id, t.name;
 ELSE
  RETURN 0;
 END IF;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Apart from the obvious invalid use of `DO` (you need `BEGIN`, please see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)) the rest doesn't really make sense either. You can't return a single integer from a function defined to return a table. And you can't access the alias `t` outside of the select inside the exists. And you would return a random row from that table - doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm trying to do if select query return not null id and name values function have to return id and name values. İf select query return null value function have to return 0;

Comment: You can not randomly return different types of results from different places in the same function. Please see my answer, explaining this is way too much for a comment. One question is: are you trying to return all rows from that table or a specific one? If a specific row, then **which** one. Your query has no `where` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `do` is for *anonymous* PL/pgSQL blocks, not for functions. In PL/PgSQL you need `begin ... end` (in fact that is needed *inside* a DO block as well)

But that would only fix the obvious syntax error regarding the incorrect `DO` usage, but it still won't work for several reasons:

You can't just return `t.id, t.name` as at that point in the code you have not assigned values to that - in fact the alias `t` does not exist outside of the select statement.

The `exists` check does not seem to make any sense. It checks if there is at least one row in the table, if there is none you are trying to some random values from that table - doesn't make sense

You also can return just a scalar value (`0`) from a function defined to return a result with two columns. You need to return at least one row with **two** columns.

---

If I had do guess: you are trying to return a "dummy row" if nothing is found. If so you could adapt [this example from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tuvimer.getProjectTypes(
   OUT id integer,
   OUT name character varying)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$$
BEGIN --<< The BEGIN goes into the body

 return query select t.id, t.name from tuvimer.tuvi_project_category t;

 IF NOT FOUND THEN
    -- return a dummy row
    return query select 0, null::character varying;
 END IF;

END; --<< And you need an END here
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

---

Unrelated, but: I prefer the syntax `returns table (id integer, name varchar)` over `returns setof record` and the definition of the columns as `OUT` parameters.

Comment: I used select * from tuvimer.getProjectTypes(); I get  ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type unknown does not match expected type character varying in column 2.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function tuvimer.getprojecttypes() line 8 at RETURN QUERY

Comment: @SezKo: you need to cast the value of the dummy row. See my edit